# How can I make all initialized integers (instance varibales) into an Array in Java?

Tags: java

If I have some initialized integers which are instance variables, for example:

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
```

Is there a way I could create an array with all of the integers without doing:

```
int[] array = {x, y};
```

I would like to not have to add the integers into the array manually.

Comment: Really? How can you make coffee, without adding necessary ingredients like milk, water, sugar?

Comment: What would count as not adding items to an array "manually"?

Answer (score 2):

If the variables are initialized to 0, then just create the array with the appropriate size:

```
int[] array = new int[10];
```

All elements in the array are initialized to 0.